# Sato-tate conjecture for elliptic curves over finite fields

Tags: elliptic-curves

I am doing a research project about elliptic curves over finite fields and I am across the Sato-tate conjecture, but I am having some difficulty understanding it.

What I (think) I took away from the reading: it states how the error term ($2\sqrt q$) in Hassse's theorem varies for different values of q

Any explanation or links to other references would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What references have you already consulted?

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo Silvermans text on elliptic curves as well as some random websites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly suggest Barry Mazur's "[Finding meaning in error terms](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2008-45-02/S0273-0979-08-01207-X/S0273-0979-08-01207-X.pdf)", Bulletin (New Series) of the American Mathematical Society, Volume 45, Number 2, April 2008, Pages 185–228.